# Grouping data but from the same source (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

This is my tabel, relation with dependent

> Table: **data_kel**

```
+---------+--------------+
| alamat  | nomor_kk     |
+---------+--------------+
| tes1    | 11           |
+---------+--------------+
| tes2    | 12           |
+---------+--------------+
| tes3    | 12           |
+---------++-------------+
| tes4    | 12           |
+---------+--------------+
| tes5    | 11           |
+---------+--------------+
```

> Table: **data_mustahik**

```
+---------+---------------+------------+
| nama    | nomor_kk      | kepala_kel |
+---------+---------------+------------+
| 11      | 11            | 1          |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 12      | 12            | 1          |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 13      | 12            | 0          |
+---------++---------------+-----------+
| 14      | 12            | 0          |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 15      | 11            | 0          |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

> Table: **data_survey**

```
   +--------------+---------------+
   | id_survey    | nomor_kk      |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 21           | 11            |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 22           | 12            |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 23           | 12            |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 24           | 12            |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 25           | 11            |
   +--------------+---------------+
```

> Table: **rekapitulasi_kelayakan**

```
+--------------+---------------+
| id_srv       | kelayakan     |
+--------------+---------------+
| 21           | layak         |
+--------------+---------------+
| 22           | tidak         |
+--------------+---------------+
| 23           | -             |
+--------------+---------------+
| 24           | -             |
+--------------+---------------+
| 25           | -             |
+--------------+---------------+
```

**OUTPUT NOW (FALSE)**

```
11 | 11 | Layak 
12 | 12 | Tidak
13 | 12 | - 
14 | 12 | -
15 | 11 | -
```

**I want to OUTPUT THIS (RIGHT)**

```
11 | 11 | Layak 
12 | 12 | Tidak
13 | 12 | Layak 
14 | 12 | Layak
15 | 11 | Tidak
```

I'm stuck to query this .. Actually this query so long .. its just simple .. 
If i using group .. the output just one not all appear ..

```
i want to grouping 
nomor_kk 11 with nama 11,15 => layak
nomor_kk 12 with nama 12,13,14 => tidak
```

my query is

```
SELECT * FROM data_mustahik dk
         INNER JOIN data_survey ds 
         ON dk.nomor_kk=ds.nomor_kk
         INNER JOIN rekapitulasi_kelayakan rk
         ON ds.id_survey=rkid_srv
```

QUery

```
CREATE TABLE data_kel
    (`alamat` varchar(5), `nomor_kk` int)
;

INSERT INTO data_kel
    (`alamat` , `nomor_kk`)
VALUES
    ('tes1', 11),
    ('tes2', 12),
    ('tes3', 12),
    ('tes4', 12),
    ('tes5', 11)
;

CREATE TABLE data_survey
    (`id_survey` int, `nomor_kk` int)
;

INSERT INTO data_survey
    (`id_survey`, `nomor_kk`)
VALUES
    (21, 11),
    (22, 12),
    (23, 12),
    (24, 12),
    (25, 11)
;




CREATE TABLE rekapitulasi_kelayakan
    (`id_srv` int, `kelayakan` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO rekapitulasi_kelayakan
    (`id_srv`, `kelayakan`)
VALUES
    (21, 'layak'),
    (22, 'tidak'),
    (23, '-'),
    (24, '-'),
    (25, '-')
;


CREATE TABLE data_mustahik
    (`nama` int, `nomor_kk` int, `kepala_kel` int)
;

INSERT INTO data_mustahik
    (`nama`, `nomor_kk`, `kepala_kel`)
VALUES
    (11, 11, 1),
    (12, 12, 1),
    (13, 12, 0),
    (14, 12, 0),
    (15, 11, 0)
;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT dk.nama,dl.alamat,rk.kelayakan FROM data_mustahik dk
INNER JOIN data_kel dl 
ON dk.nomor_kk=dl.nomor_kk
INNER JOIN data_survey ds 
ON dk.nomor_kk=ds.nomor_kk
INNER JOIN rekapitulasi_kelayakan rk
ON ds.id_survey=rk.id_srv
WHERE rk.kelayakan != '-'
order by nama
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first row be `A 11 Layak` because `A` has `id_survey = 12` and `id_srv = 12` has `kelayakan = Layak`?

Comment: It looks like your first query works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db88a/2

Comment: im sorry i just update the question .. i using 3 table

Comment: `data_mustahik.nomor_kk` links to multiple rows in `data_survey`, so you get multiple rows in the results for each of them. How is it supposed to know which one to use? Maybe you just need `WHERE kelayakan != '-'`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the rows with `-` in the `keleyakan` column.

```
SELECT * FROM data_mustahik dk
INNER JOIN data_survey ds 
ON dk.nomor_kk=ds.nomor_kk
INNER JOIN rekapitulasi_kelayakan rk
ON ds.id_survey=rk.id_srv
WHERE rk.kelayakan != '-'
order by nama
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76a45/2)

Comment: Okey that query success.. but if using kepala_kel for relation ..  ? it can be ?

Comment: What does `kepala_kel` relate to? I don't speak your language, so I don'tg even know what that means.

Comment: kepala_kel for get value  kelayakan in rekapitulasi_kelayakan .. not using this -> WHERE rk.kelayakan != '-'

Comment: I still don't understand. How does 0/1 in `kepala_kel` relate to anything in `rekapitulasi_kelayakan`?

Comment: hey @barmar may i ask again.. i just updated the question .. Thank you

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do, instead of just posting tables with meaningless names (they might mean something in your language, but to me they're nonsense)?